# Почему координаты разные?

Tags: unity3d

Добрый вечер!
Ниже скриншоты, сделанные в Unity. На первом выбрана камера, на втором блок.

**Камера**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Блок**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В красных прямоугольниках координаты объектов. В обоих случаях всё должно быть по нулям. Из-за чего возможна такая разница?

Comment: Покажите скрин с иерархией объектов, где будет выбран этот блок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например блок расположен в каком-либо предке, а предок смещен в сторону. В итоге, чтобы выровнять потомка в (0,0) приходится его смещать в противоположную сторону смещения предка.

Comment: То есть, это координаты относительно предка?

Comment: @Николай да....